# Mongodb $elemMatch get documents matching empty array

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible, using `$elemMatch`, to retrieve documents matching an empty array ?

Imagine the following documents:

```
{ a: [] }          (A)       
{ a: [{ b: 1 }] }  (B)
{ a: [{ b: 2 }]} } (C)
```

What I would like is a query that uses $elemMatch and that find all documents in which `a.b` is not 1. Because in (A) `a.b` does not exists, it should be returned.
However, with the query

```
db.z.find({ a: { $elemMatch: {b: { $ne: 1 }} } })
```

Only (C) is returned. I understand the behavior as their is no element in the `a` array but is their a way to work around this behavior to also return (A) ? Or does another mongodb operator have this behavior ?

Adding `{ b: { $nin: [1, null] } }` or `{ b: { $ne: 1, $exists: true } }` does not work.

Edit: to use $or before $elemMatch works but my question is about modifying $elemMatch, not to add an operator before it.

Comment: *Edit: to use $or before ... an operator before it* What is the purpose of doing this with `$elemMatch`? Is there something which is not suitable to obtain you the desired result with the `$or`? Or is there any performance issue with `$or`? You cannot use `$elemMatch` with the array where the value does even exists.

Comment: This request is just a simplified version of a way bigger search engine. I cannot use `$or` before `a` because this request is already in a `$or`, in a `$match`, in an aggregation pipeline... If I have to use an operator before `a`, I will have   to modify a lot of code in my search engine.
The better would be an alternative to `$elemMatch`, an option to add or an operator I can use in combination with it.
`$or` is my last solution

Comment: @JérémyPouyet Take a look this workaround: https://mongoplayground.net/p/BfPgZFyJfw2